# django: Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

[image: Project view]

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('todo.urls')),
]
```

setting.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

todo/ulrs.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("login", views.home),
]
```

todo/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

[image]

I don't know why it is not showing my page...
I have created django project called taskly. And in that project I have only 1 app called todo. I have referred templates folder as well as you can see above. In that template folder there is only 1 page index.html

Comment: remove the slash at the end of the URL when you type it in the browser

Comment: Astrologers announced a week of trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yout should add '/' after login and path name,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", views.home, name="login"),
]
```

if it doesn't work add the HTML link tag in question to let me check

Answer (score 1):

If you want the endpoint as "login" not "login/" then in `settings.py` add `APPEND_SLASH=False` by default it is set to be false [check the docs for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).

This is one of the core features of Django where it adds a "trailing slash" automatically.

Django will redirect 301 automatically. You can see the logs like this:

```bash
"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 301 0
"GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6596
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
path("login", views.home),
```

Try this:

```
path("login/", views.home), #added forward slash here
```